# How to unify date format using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time, datetime-parsing

I need to parse different time format into `BASIC_ISO_DATE`. Right now, there are 4 types of date format:

- `2016-10-01` (ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
- `2016T`
- `201610T`
- `2016-02-07T22:03:39.937Z` (ISO 8601)

Need to parse to `20161001` and print out, with default day is `01`, default month `Jan`. Examples:

- `2016T` -> `20160101`
- `201610T` -> `20161001`

How can I use `DateTimeFormatter` to achieve this?

Comment: Do you need just the date (a `LocalDate`) in all cases? Or do you need the time of day too when there is one (the last example)?

Comment: I don’t understand how month can be January in `20161001`? A typo?

Comment: @OleV.V. I think it's not a typo. If there's a month (in this case, `10`), only the day defaults to `1`. If there's no month, then it defaults to January.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to complement [@Flown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45751114/7605325) (which works perfectly BTW), you can also use optional patterns (delimited by `[]`):

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // optional ISO8601 date/time and offset
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
    // optional yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyT or yyyyMMT
    .appendPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd][yyyy'T'][yyyyMM'T']")
    // default day is 1
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1L)
    // default month is January
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1L)
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
```

This works exactly the same way. You can choose which one is clearer or easier to maintain. If there are **lots** of different patterns, using `[]` might end up being more confusing, IMO.

Note that I used `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` instead of `ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`. The only difference is that `ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` also accepts a timezone name in the end (like `[Europe/London]`), while `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` doesn't. [Check the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You could build your own `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME)
  .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
  .appendOptional(new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
    .optionalStart()
      .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
    .optionalEnd()
    .appendLiteral('T')
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1L)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1L)
    .toFormatter())
  .toFormatter();
String[] strings = {"2016-10-01", "2016T", "201610T", "2016-02-07T22:03:39.937Z"};
for (String s : strings) {
  System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(s, dateTimeFormatter)
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public LocalDate parse(String str) {
   // Might want to add some checks here...
   String text = (str.replaceAll("[\-T]", "") + "0101").substring(0, 8);
   return LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just one `DateTimeFormatter`, [Flown’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45751114/5772882) is well thought out and lends itself pretty well to adding more possible formats or changing the requirements in other ways.

I think a simple alternative is that you use three or four `DateTimeFormatter` objects and try them in turn until one works.

For `2016T`, you may either use `parseDefaulting()` as in Flown’s answer or just parse into a `Year` and then use for example `.atDay(1)`. Similarly for `201610T`: one option is to parse into a `YearMonth` and use its `atDay()`.

My solution may be less elegant, but possibly clearer to read.