# Parsing an ISO 8601 date in Java8 when all fields (including separators, but not including years) are optional

Tags: java, java-8

I have a requirement for parsing ISO8601 formatted strings in Java with various levels of accuracy. Some examples of the string I need to parse are:

- 2018
- 2018-10
- 2018-10-15
- 2018-10-15T12:00
- 2018-10-15T12:00:30
- 2018-10-15T12:00:30.123
- 20181015
- 201810151200
- 20181015120030
- 20181015120030.123
- 20181015T12:00:30.123

Where I don't have a field then I am free to assume the lowest valid value that applies (for example, if the month is missing I can assume January, if the day is missing then assume the first of the month and if the time is missing assume midnight)

I've searched SO and all the examples I've found all assume that I know the exact format in advance.

Comment: Possible (near) duplicate of [What is the Standard way to Parse different Dates passed as Query-Params to the REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558859/what-is-the-standard-way-to-parse-different-dates-passed-as-query-params-to-the). There are already quite a number of questions about parsing date-time strings that may come in several formats.

Comment: I’d define a common formatter for the first 6 formats, with optional parts and `parseDefaulting`, and then a common format for the last four in a similar way. Then try each of the two formatters in turn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unify date format using DateTimeFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748065/how-to-unify-date-format-using-datetimeformatter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that took me longer than I had expected. The only valid parser is:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
        .appendPattern("[['-']MM[['-']dd[['T']HH[[':']mm[[':']ss['.'SSS]]]]]]")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0)
        .toFormatter();

String[] s = {
        "2018",
        "2018-10",
        "2018-10-15",
        "2018-10-15T12:00",
        "2018-10-15T12:00:30",
        "2018-10-15T12:00:30.123",
        "20181015",
        "201810151200",
        "20181015120030",
        "20181015120030.123",
        "20181015T12:00:30.123"
};
for (String line : s) {
  System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(line, dtf));
}
```

---

The problem is that `yyyy` creates a `ValueParser(minWidth=4, maxWidth=19, SignStyle.PAD_EXEEDS)` which parses the date `20181015` as `year=20181015` as an example. So we have to restrict the digit width of `year` to 4.

The documentation states:

> **Year**: The count of letters determines the minimum field width below which padding is used.

But does not specify a maximum width.

Comment: Thanks for the solution - I've have never have spotted the issue with the year being 19 digits. Certainly the error messages I've been looking at don't help

Comment: I also had to debug the `DateTimeFormatter` internals to see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For the first cases with separators (`-`, `:`) one can use:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("uuuu[-MM[-dd[['T']HH[:]mm[[:]ss[[.]SSS]]]]]");
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    TemporalAccessor result = dtf.parse(text, pos);
```

However neither `uuuuMMdd` nor `[-]` or `['-']` worked for me in Java 8.

Comment: the pattern `appendPattern("yyyy[[-]MM[[-]dd[['T']HH[[:]mm[[:]ss]]]]]")` ALMOST works! For some reason the only separator I required is between the month and the year.

Comment: @Stormcloud Yes, weird; I also got results on the last half without `-` but `parseBest/parseUnresolved` all lead to unsatisfying results; for me, for the time that I tried. Teaches humility.

Answer (score 0):

create a lookup table of DateFormatters or whatever you're using based on the length of the input String and the occurrence of 'T'

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DateTimeFormatter` with `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, which has a method called `parseDefaulting()`. `parseDefaulting()` could set the default value if there is no matching.