# String to Date object in Android

Tags: java, datetime, android-date, date, android-dateutils

I have two string values in one key for the date

Case 1 : date can be a string value ="2010-10-15T09:27:37Z"

Case 2 : and sometimes it can be a "20130526160000"

but I have only one function to parse these two value into date object

how can i identify that current value for date is case 1 or case 2 so that i can parse and will not get error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing an ISO 8601 date in Java8 when all fields (including separators, but not including years) are optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815456/parsing-an-iso-8601-date-in-java8-when-all-fields-including-separators-but-not). There are a number of similar questions, please search.

Comment: A potential issue is the first format includes offset (`Z`) and the second one doesn’t. Do you know in which time zone or offset to interpret the latter? More generally, what is the expected result in each case?

Answer (score 1):

If there are only these two cases, you can check whether the string contains literal `T` or `Z`.